# discontinuity point of a monotone function of $R^n$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I am aware that a monotone function from $R$ to $R$ has an at most countable points of discontinuity. Can we say that the set of points of discontinuity of a monotone function from $R^n$ to $R$ defined in a component wise order is of first category (cf. http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/107460/ArchMathRetro_029-1993-1_2.pdf)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the paper you refer to it is proved that the discontinuity set of monotone
functions $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ has Lebesgue measure zero. Combining that
with the fact that the discontinuity set of any map into a metric space is 
$F_\sigma$ yields a positive answer.

The discontinuity set can be written as $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty F_n$ where each $F_n$
is closed. If it has measure 0, every $F_n$ also has measure 0, therefore, 
because every nonempty open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has positive measure, their
interior must be empty. A closed set with empty interior is nowhere dense,
so we can conclude that the union is meagre.